# Create scatter plot with third dimension and multiple colors

Tags: r, plot, axis

**Purpose**

Create scatter plot with third dimension and multiple colors.

First:
- 3rd dimension with another scale in contrast to y-axis
- create two colors (this is done using col, see code)

Sketch simulating the purpose:

[image]

**Code**

Two "containers" of points plotted in this way:

```
plot(1:3, c(3,3,3))
points(1:3, c(2,2,2), col="blue")
```

Another nice plotting is done by:

```
#install.packages("hexbin")
library(hexbin)
x <- 1:1000#rnorm(1000)
y <- 1500:501#rnorm(1000)
bin<-hexbin(x, y, xbins=50)
plot(bin, main="Hexagonal Binning")
```

But I do not know how to use hexbin (I do not understand the functionality). There are needed two colors which I do not know how to generate.

**Questions**

1. How to create the 3rd axis with other scaling than the y-axis?
2. Can I use ´hexbin´ to get the result?

Comment: Do you want a 3D plot, or just another axis on a 2D plot? If 2D, add `par(new=TRUE)` before calling the second set of data, and plot the second set of data with the `ylim()` that you want. Happy to add an example as an answer if you'd like.

Comment: @Jared Smith: I want only another axis (y axis) on a 2D plot like in the example figure above from -10 to 10 (y axis has -4 to 5). Using plot(1:3, c(3,3,3))
par(new=TRUE)
points(1:3, c(2,2,2), col="blue", ylim=c(-10,10)) Im getting the same result. Please give an example or an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, using `points()` does not work, but using `plot()` does work:

```
#Set margin on right side to be a bit larger
par(mar = c(5,4.5,4,5))
#Plot first set of data
plot(1:3, rep(3,3), ylim=c(-5,5), xlab="X-Axis", ylab="Y-Axis 1")
#Plot second set of data on different axis.
par(new=T)
plot(1:3, rep(5,3), ylim=c(-10,10), col="blue", xlab="", ylab="", axes=FALSE)
#Add numbers and labels to the second y-axis
mtext("Y-Axis 2",side=4,line=3) 
axis(4, ylim=c(-10,10))
```

Comment: Thank you! Im wondering why here calling ´plot´ second time works drawing new points. But hopefully it works.

Comment: Do you know anything about the function ´hexbin´? Or how can I change the round points for example to stars or rectangles?

Comment: Look at the `pch` parameter for plot. There are many options for point characters.